# Ruby On Rails each method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I want to call .each on @users and in my erb I have:

```
<% @user.each do |user| %>
<p><%= user.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Simple enough. But after every 5th user I need to add a clearfix of this:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: whats Rails-specific about this question? ps. Use better CSS that doesn't require changing the markup for the sake of presentation.

Comment: @sevenseacat Post an answer with a method for doing that, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) should be ok:

```
<% @users.each_with_index do |user, index| %>
  <p><%= user.name %></p>
  <% if (index + 1) % 5 == 0 %>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you mean: `index+1 % 5` because 4 will be the 5th user, won't it?

Comment: @Surya be careful with precedence. `(index + 1) % 5`

Comment: @Surya Thanks. I didn't notice "after" word in question.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [`.each_slice`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice) will be another way to provide this functionality:

```
<% @users.each_slice(5) do |users| %>
   <% users.each do |user| %>
      <p><%= user.name %></p>
   <% end %>
   <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Not seen `each_slice` before.  It looks the same as `in_groups_of` but without the annoying behaviour of padding the groups with `nil`.